# Code Gear RAD Studio Delphi 2007 can't find package error opening pas file

Tags: delphi, package, delphi-2007

After renaming a folder that contains some bpls used by IDE, on start I got the following message related to packages contained in the renamed folder:

> "Can't load package packagefile.bpl. Do you want to attempt to load
>   this package the next time a project is loaded?"

Unfortunately, for a few files, I selected "No". Now the folder has the previous name again.. but on opening certain pas files, I get some errors like (Translated):

> "Impossible to start application because dclpackagefile.bpl can't be
>   found on computer. Try to reinstall".

As a precisation, "dclpackagefile.bpl" is "dclrx100.bpl" but I suppose there will be other errors after resolving this.
Could someone help me understanding what to do in order to resolve?
Please ask if you need any further informations.

Comment: You renamed the folder containing your BPLs... naturally this broke your compile.  The compiler needs to know where these BPLs are - if you move them you have to update your library references.  http://docs.embarcadero.com/products/rad_studio/radstudio2007/RS2007_helpupdates/HUpdate4/EN/html/devcommon/delphilibrary_xml.html

Comment: If you have said NO to some of these dialogs than I believe that Delphi will have kept a record somewhere in the registry to not try to reload these packages.  You easiest solution will probably be to remove the packages and then reinstall them.

Comment: Resolved by reinstalling packages, thanks to all